# Does anyone know how to create this special shape with the use of geo nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create something that looks like stairs or something simliar. It is important that the shape has a perfect transition in the topview but has offsets in the heigts so if something drops it will drop onto the next stair. Thanks for every idea

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be done with geo nodes?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3):

one way of doing that is this:

[image]

[image]